# css only portrait mode on android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, css

My webapp needs to be working only on portrait mode on mobile phone but now I got 2 problems.

on the pc the webapp isn't showed because a pc is in landscape mode, how can i fix this?

the second problem is the most important that needed to be fixed, if i'm using a keyboard on my mobile phone, the content isn't showable. its show me the landscape div.

```
#landscape {
display: none;
}
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
    #wrapper {
        display:block;
    }
}
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
    #wrapper {
        display:none;
    }
    #landscape{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

anyone knows this problem?

Comment: I dont understand your second question. Can you describe it in different way? Maybe some pic, code etc.

Comment: @Kinga, if i click on a textfield i get a keyboard, so that i can wrote a word in the textfield. but if you click on the textfield it go's in landscape mode or something because i get the landscape mode message. when i click a textbox.

Comment: ", if i click on a textfield i get a keyboard, so that i can wrote a word in the textfield." - behaviour you want to achieve?
"but if you click on the textfield.." - what happening now?
" get the landscape mode message" - what kind of message?

Comment: i fixed it with a min-width to the last media. @Kinga i get a message that i wrote because i dont want to people can go landscape mode. so i disabled it with this code above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add second media queries for desktop with min-width to not catch smaller devices.

eg.
@media handheld and (min-width: 20em), screen and (min-width: 20em)

Comment: yeah i did something like that,
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){